# Flutter : How to remove duplicates Json Object list

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to remove duplicated Profilemodel by name only  in items list ,  so I should get NO duplicated items in screen.
I want to remove duplicated Profilemodel by name only  in items list ,  so I should get NO duplicated items in screen.

I used `items.toSet().toList()` but its not work with my need.

[image: What I want]

[image: What I DONT want]

Full code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      // Application name
      title: 'Flutter Hello World',
      // Application theme data, you can set the colors for the application as
      // you want
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      // A widget which will be started on application startup
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}
List<Profilemodel> items = [
  Profilemodel( age: 20 , name: 'Ahmed' ) ,
  Profilemodel( age: 30 , name: 'Fatma' ),
  Profilemodel( age: 15 , name: 'Ahmed' ),
  Profilemodel( age: 15 , name: 'jon' ),
  Profilemodel( age: 25 , name: 'Fatma' )];
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body : ListView.builder(
itemBuilder: (context, index){
  return ListTile(
    title: Text('${items[index].name}'),
  );
},
          itemCount: items.length,
        )

    );
  }
}

class Profilemodel{
  final String name;
  final int age;
  Profilemodel({this.name , this.age});
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess that you have not overriden the `==` operator (and consequently `hashCode`) in your `Profilemodel` class. Hence `items.toSet().toList()` might not work as you expected.

If you need a very simple solution, you can try something like this,

```dart
List<People> items = [
  Profilemodel( age: 20 , name: 'Ahmed' ) ,
  Profilemodel( age: 30 , name: 'Fatma' ),
  Profilemodel( age: 15 , name: 'Ahmed' ),
  Profilemodel( age: 15 , name: 'jon' ),
  Profilemodel( age: 25 , name: 'Fatma' )
];
final Map<String, People> profileMap = new Map();
items.forEach((item) {
  profileMap[item.name] = item;
});
items = profileMap.values.toList();
```

Or you can always try to override what I mentioned in the above. Read [this article](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#equality) for more information on it.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways you can try to remove duplicates items from a list.
for example you can convert your list to a set collection.

```
Set<Profilemodel> set = new Set<Profilemodel>.from(items );
```